# Create a RESTful action without collisions

Tags: rest, http, url

I have a simple API that deals with physical seats allocation in a room.

Each seat is the following resource:

```
{
  "person_name": "Jermie" // Person sitting in the seat
  "available": False // Seat is currently allocated
  "seat_id": 1111 // Unique seat identifier
}
```

- Receiving all seats translates to `GET /api/seats`.
- Receiving a seat state (who is sitting on it)  - `GET /api/seats/<seat_id>`
- Creating a new seat - `POST /api/seat`.
- Removing a seat - `DELETE /api/seat/<seat_id>`.

How can I create a REST API that assigns an empty seat to a user?

I can use `GET /api/seats?available=True&count=1` to return an empty seat (`1234`), and assign it - `PUT /api/seats/1234` with body of `{"available": False, "person_name": Robbie}`.

The problem with that approach is that I have a large amount of requests. Two people running the search for an empty seat at the same time, will cause the same seat to be assigned twice.

I can try `POST /api/seats/1234/assign` and return `HTTP 409 CONFLICT` if it's already assigned but this will cause many conflicts to occur, and soon enough clients will keep racing between each other trying over and over again.

Another option with be to use `POST /api/assignSeat`. This approach however is not RESTful.

This is a very simple issue, I'm probably not the first to encounter it, but "HATEOAS" and many other terms that I've encountered along the way do not actually give a solution. It's quite fundamental to my and other people's understanding.

Is it possible for me to create such an API while following REST principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you interpret 'REST = CRUD'. I think this is a useful pattern and a great default for REST apis.

However, there are cases where this default doesn't work too well. What you're describing sounds like one of those cases.

So having a special RPC-like endpoint that is used with POST for this specific case sounds like good architecture to me. It's also not strictly not-RESTful.

REST describes how the web works, and HTML forms are an integral part of the Web. Many HATEOAS formats have a way to describe such an 'action', and those formats are probably the closest to *actual* REST then you can get.

Comment: I highly appreciate your quick response. How would you implement this using HATEOAS? Would `/api` return an "assign" link? Would `/api/seats` return it (together with a huge dump of the entire database)? Assigning an empty seat surely isn't relevant for a specific `/api/seats/<seat>`.

Comment: If (one of) the prime functions of the client is to find a seat, I'd probably show that action right from the 'home document'. e.g.: the first endpoint the API hits. The link could indeed have the rel `assign-seat`. If you use HAL, you could sever a 'HAL Form' from the endpoint: https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/

Comment: sever should have been 'serve'